# Unable to read xml hierarchy using python

Tags: python

I am trying to read xml file using python. My xml file look like this:

```
<item_details>
    <item id="0001" type="donut">
        <name>Bicuit</name>
        <ppu>0.55</ppu>
        <batters>
            <batter id="1002"><name>Chocolate</name></batter>
            <batter id="1003"><name>Blueberry</name></batter>
        </batters>
        <toppings>
            <topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
            <topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
            <topping id="5006">Sprinkles</topping>
        </toppings>
    </item>
</item_details>
```

I am using the following python code to read this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
nestedtree = ElementTree.parse(nestedxml)
nestedroot = nestedtree.getroot()

for item in nestedroot.findall('item'):
    itid = item.get('id')
    ittype = item.get('type')
    itname = item.find('name').text
    itppu = item.find('ppu').text
    for batter in item.find('batters'):
        baid = batter.get('id')
        battername = batter.find('name').text
        for topping in item.find('toppings'):
            toppingid = topping.get('id')
            tname = topping.find('topping')
            print(itid, ittype, itname, baid, battername,toppingid, tname)
```

However I am not able to read the topping details. I am getting only the below output with topping name as "**none**":

```
0001 donut Bicuit 1002 Chocolate 5002 None
0001 donut Bicuit 1002 Chocolate 5005 None
0001 donut Bicuit 1002 Chocolate 5006 None
0001 donut Bicuit 1003 Blueberry 5002 None
0001 donut Bicuit 1003 Blueberry 5005 None
0001 donut Bicuit 1003 Blueberry 5006 None
```

Need suggestion, how to read the below xml format:

```
<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you try  tname =  topping.txt instead of tname = topping.find('topping')?

Comment: thanks mate, its worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, for reference only.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<item_details>
    <item id="0001" type="donut">
        <name>Bicuit</name>
        <ppu>0.55</ppu>
        <batters>
            <batter id="1002"><name>Chocolate</name></batter>
            <batter id="1003"><name>Blueberry</name></batter>
        </batters>
        <toppings>
            <topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
            <topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
            <topping id="5006">Sprinkles</topping>
        </toppings>
    </item>
</item_details>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
for item in doc.selects('item'):
  itid,ittype,itname,itppu = item.id,item.type,item.name.text,item.ppu.text
  for id in item.selects('batter|topping'):
    print(itid,ittype,itname,itppu,id.id,id.text)
```

Result:

```
0001 donut Bicuit 0.55 1002 Chocolate
0001 donut Bicuit 0.55 1003 Blueberry
0001 donut Bicuit 0.55 5002 Glazed
0001 donut Bicuit 0.55 5005 Sugar
0001 donut Bicuit 0.55 5006 Sprinkles
```